# setTimeout is instant in function called on load

Tags: javascript

I can't understand why the switchImage() function gets called immediately after the page is loading instead of waiting three seconds.

```
function initSlideshow() {

   //Do some initialization stuff first

   window.setTimeout(switchImage(),3000);
}

function switchImage() {
   alert();
}

window.onload = initSlideshow;
```

You can see the actual page in action [here](http://mayar.abertay.ac.uk/~1204925/coursework/slideshow.php)

Comment: You're executing the function rather than passing the function reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling it since you have the ()

```
window.setTimeout(switchImage(),3000);
                            ^^^
```

This is how you assign it, you drop the ()

```
window.setTimeout(switchImage,3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `()` immediately invoke the function, omit `()` to pass the function along rather than call it immediately.

```
window.setTimeout(switchImage,3000);
```